# Error handling of multiple class attributes

Tags: excel, vba

I have a class that holds data in separate attributes (I chose this design instead of an array or scripting.dictionary because I will be using these data for the construction of a decision tree and I want to make use of IntelliType while I construct it.).

The data are loaded from an excel spreadsheet in the form of floats, so I am storing them in a long datatype, but from time to time it happens so that a value is missing and is replaced by an "NA" string.

I would like to create an error-handling routine, that, if a non-numeric value is encountered, would replace the content with a value -1.

I know I could do this with checking with IsNumeric() or error-handling, but I don't know how to make it work for every one of the many attributes the class holds and I don't really like the solution to write a specific error-handling code for every one of them (storing each of them in a separate attribute is not elegant as well, but I find this a price I am willing to pay for the advantage of shorter syntax in the decision tree).

Is there a way to pass a value to a variable, that just encountered a type-mismatch error, by the error-handling code independent of the variable name?

A simple example with several of the attributes:

```
Option Explicit
Dim B_LYM           As Long
Dim B_mem           As Long
Dim B_CXCR3         As Long
Dim B_CXCR4_MFI     As Long

Public Sub SetData(data as Range)
    On Error Goto err_handler

    B_LYM = data.Cells(1, 1)
    B_mem = data.Cells(1, 2)
    B_CXCR3 = data.Cells(1, 3)
    B_CXCR4_MFI = data.Cells(1, 4)

err_handler:
    'I need something like this:
    'if valuebeingstored = "NA" then targetvariable = -1
End Sub
```

It could be that some other approach could be better and I am gladly open to options, I only want to emphasize that I would really like make use of IntelliType when constructing the decision tree. I was considering using scripting.dictionary, but the syntax will bloat the code very quickly.

Comment: `specific error-handling code for every one of them` - it would appear that you'd only have one error handling code that you use for all of them. And you don't even need to write it. `B_LYM = Application.IfNa(data.Cells(1, 1), -1)`, `B_mem = Application.IfNa(data.Cells(1, 2), -1)`...

Comment: Write a single function, e.g. `getCell(row,col)` that checks the input and returns the value or-1 when validation fails.

Comment: Is your example code a part of what you are using, or just a dummy one to show us what is it about? If the the column is incrementing as in your code you can place all the variables in an array, iterate between the array elements and use the incremented count as column. Using `Application.IfNa(val, -1)`, as GSerg suggested, will make useless any need of error handling. It is (such) a error avoiding...

Comment: @FaneDuru yes, I know that, but how would I then iterate over the attributes to store the values in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you have a `Class` and therefore could include the function to check the input and return -1 inside the class and use the `Get` and `Let` properties to call the function.

Here is an example class (named `clsDataStuff`) demonstrating this:

```
Option Explicit

Private c_B_LYM As Double
Private c_B_mem As Double
Private c_B_CXCR3 As Double
Private c_B_CXCR4_MFI As Double

Public Property Let B_LYM(varValue As Variant)
    c_B_LYM = ParseDouble(varValue)
End Property
Public Property Get B_LYM()
    B_LYM = c_B_LYM
End Property

Public Property Let B_mem(varValue As Variant)
    c_B_mem = ParseDouble(varValue)
End Property
Public Property Get B_mem()
    B_mem = c_B_mem
End Property

Public Property Let B_CXCR3(varValue As Variant)
    c_B_CXCR3 = ParseDouble(varValue)
End Property
Public Property Get B_CXCR3()
    B_CXCR3 = c_B_CXCR3
End Property

Public Property Let B_CXCR4_MFI(varValue As Variant)
    c_B_CXCR4_MFI = ParseDouble(varValue)
End Property
Public Property Get B_CXCR4_MFI()
    B_CXCR4_MFI = c_B_CXCR4_MFI
End Property

Private Function ParseDouble(varValue As Variant) As Double
    If IsNumeric(varValue) Then
        ParseDouble = CDbl(varValue)
    Else
        ParseDouble = -1
    End If
End Function
```

Noting that:

- the `Let` property expects a `Variant` because you say your input could be a number, or a string
- the `Get` property returns `Double` as you said your inputs are floats so [`Double`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary) is better than `Long`
- the `ParseDouble` function simply checks for a numeric input and returns -1 otherwise

Then, in your module code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim B_LYM           As Long
Dim B_mem           As Long
Dim B_CXCR3         As Long
Dim B_CXCR4_MFI     As Long

Public Sub Test()

    Dim objDataStuff As clsDataStuff
    
    Set objDataStuff = New clsDataStuff
    
    objDataStuff.B_LYM = 1 'data.Cells(1, 1)
    objDataStuff.B_mem = 2 'data.Cells(1, 2)
    objDataStuff.B_CXCR3 = "a" 'data.Cells(1, 3)
    objDataStuff.B_CXCR4_MFI = True 'data.Cells(1, 4)

    Debug.Print objDataStuff.B_LYM
    Debug.Print objDataStuff.B_mem
    Debug.Print objDataStuff.B_CXCR3
    Debug.Print objDataStuff.B_CXCR4_MFI

End Sub
```

Returns an output of:

```
 1 
 2 
-1 
-1
```

Intellisense is available and you get validation of the input:

[image]

***Edit - regarding the comment on dynamically setting a target variable.***

Your class can be:

```
Option Explicit

Public B_LYM As Double
Public B_mem As Double
Public B_CXCR3 As Double
Public B_CXCR4_MFI As Double

Public Sub SetVar(ByVal strVarName As String, ByVal varValue As Variant)
    Dim dblValue As Double
    Dim strToEval As String
    
    If Not MemberExists(strVarName) Then Exit Sub
    
    dblValue = ParseDouble(varValue) ' do the parse
    CallByName Me, strVarName, VbLet, dblValue ' dynamically assign the value
    
End Sub

Private Function ParseDouble(varValue As Variant) As Double
    If IsNumeric(varValue) Then
        ParseDouble = CDbl(varValue)
    Else
        ParseDouble = -1
    End If
End Function

Private Function MemberExists(strVarName) As Boolean
    Dim blnTest As Boolean
    Dim varValue As Variant
    
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    varValue = CallByName(Me, strVarName, VbGet)
    blnTest = True
    GoTo ExitFunction

ErrHandler:
    blnTest = False
ExitFunction:
    MemberExists = blnTest

End Function
```

Where:

- All the variables are `Public` and you still get Intellisense but avoid all the repetitive `Let` and `Get` code
- A single `SetVar` method uses [`CallByName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/callbyname-function) to dynamically set a target variable

Two problems:

1. You need the clunky `MemberExists` function to prevent `SetVar` trying to assign a value to a member that does not exist - otherwise this generates an error (438) but perhaps this is something you need in your logic ?
2. You can still assign values to the target variable with e.g. `objDataStuff.B_CXR3 = "foo"` which alsos produces an error for anything other than a number.

The example code shows the problem below. But sticking with `SetVar` method will produce the same output as above.

```
Option Explicit
 
Dim B_LYM           As Long
Dim B_mem           As Long
Dim B_CXCR3         As Long
Dim B_CXCR4_MFI     As Long

Public Sub Test()

    Dim objDataStuff As clsDataStuff
    
    Set objDataStuff = New clsDataStuff
       
    objDataStuff.SetVar "B_LYM", 1
    objDataStuff.SetVar "B_mem", 2
    objDataStuff.SetVar "B_CXCR3", -1
    objDataStuff.SetVar "B_CXCR4_MFI", True
    objDataStuff.SetVar "foobar", 999
    ' working around SetVar here generates an error
    objDataStuff.B_CXCR3 = "bad"
    
    Debug.Print objDataStuff.B_LYM
    Debug.Print objDataStuff.B_mem
    Debug.Print objDataStuff.B_CXCR3
    Debug.Print objDataStuff.B_CXCR4_MFI

End Sub
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you very much for a prompt answer. This solves my problem. Just a followup question: do I get it correctly that there is no way in VBA to perform an action during set/let function on a "dynamic" target variable without writing a specific set/let function for each specific variable in question?

Comment: @OndřejJanča - yes, see my edit, but there are some risks attached

Comment: @ Robin Mackenzie Man, this is what I needed. The CallByName. Thank you for the extensive insight into the possible problems and error-handling possibilities.